# Map over all objects in an array

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array of type as in picture [image]

I am passing these Ids for fetching twitter embedd cards.

I want to loop over all of these to generate whole new array. I tried to test the loop for [0] index as below and received data properly in twitter cards:

```
let positive_data = positive.data;
let tweetIDS = positive_data[0].tweetids;
          console.log(tweetIDS);

let tweet_positive = tweetIDS.split(',').map(key => ({
    val: key
}));
console.log(tweet_positive);
```

console screenshots:

[image]
How do I loop over for all the items from index[0] to index[3] ?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: "*How do I loop over for all the items from index[0] to index[3] ?*" by using `positive_data.map`?

Comment: post your same array format

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var sampleArray = [
 ["100,101,102"],
 ["200,201,202"],
 ["300,301,302"]
];
sampleArray = sampleArray.flat();
var newArray = [];
sampleArray.forEach(data=>newArray.push(...data.split(",")));
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: I tried on my array and it returned `data.split is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to create a flattened array of objects by splitting each `tweetids` and mapping over them:

```js
const positive_data = [{ tweetids: "1,2,3" },
{ tweetids: "4,5,6" },
{ tweetids: "7,8,9" },
{ tweetids: "10,12,13" }]

const output = positive_data
                  .flatMap(a => a.tweetids.split(",").map(val => ({ val })))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: The `slice(0, 4)` might be superfluous - I think OP meant they wanted to loop over all and the indexes available in the data there were 0-3, hence why these specific numbers are mentioned.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, probably